# Crop and Resize image from X and Y Position

Tags: php, image, resize, crop

I'm trying to crop then resize an image on `PHP v5.4`, I've read these resources

- [Put PNG over a JPG in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269363/put-png-over-a-jpg-in-php)
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.phPP
- [PHP watermarking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726894/php-watermarking)
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php

My code is based off the answer from [Cropping image in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008911/cropping-image-in-php) (the dimensions between these images vary alot).

I want to resize this image from `1151x768` to `200x82` and crop the background section at `x: 0, y: 686`

I'd prefer not bloating the question with the entire 600 lines in this question, `$output` refers to `setwidth1200nzpioneerthursday08398` image

```
<?php

$output = imagecreatefromjpeg("setwidth1200nzpioneerthursday08398.jpg");

$source_crop_image = imagecreatetruecolor(200, 82);

if(!is_resource($source_crop_image)) {
    return $source_crop_image;
}


imagealphablending($output, true);
$source_copy_result = imagecopy($output, $source_crop_image, 0, 0, 0, 686, 200, 82);
$source_copy_result = (bool) $source_copy_result;

if(!$source_copy_result) {
    return false;
}

$source_image_result = imagejpeg($source_crop_image, "images/mynewimage.jpg");
$source_image_result = (bool) $source_image_result;


?>
```

My Image `setwidth1200nzpioneerthursday08398`

[image: Sample Image]

Ideally I'm trying to get it crop the RED SECTION, while keeping the scale intact then resizing to `200x82`

[image: Crop Section]

My Result

[image: Result Image]

My Expected Result (I created this image using GIMP).

[image: Expected Result]

I have no idea why my resulting image is a black box ..

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have imagecopy() arguments in wrong order.

The right one is `$source_copy_result = imagecopy($source_crop_image, $output, 0, 0, 0, 686, 200, 82);`